# redirect tcpdump generated pcap file to another server while packets are being captured

Tags: python, tcpdump, nc

I was looking for some command like this, it achieves:

1. redirect the tcpdump generated pcap file to another server
2. during the process of 1., using a python script or some tool to analyze each packet.

So from the point of the system user, when packets are being captured, s/he could both view the packets like in wireshark, and download a pcap file. Because the analyzing procedure could consume quite a some system resources, so I hope the pcap file could be redirected to another server, and run analysis on that server. Now the problem is, `nc` listener quits when `tcpdump` is killed (I have tried `-15`), while I hope the listener could still be running, because there may be several servers running `tcpdump`.

`tcpdump -i eth0 port 8801 -w a.pcap | nc 192.168.12.5 9901`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set tcpdump to output raw PCAP data to standard out and utilize SSH as your transport mechanism to have that data written to a remote file on the remote analysis host, as a continuous stream.

Example:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 port 8801 -w - | ssh ${remote_host} "cat >> $(hostname).pcap"
```

In the above example, I've used `$(hostname)` to evaluate the hostname of the server (where the tcpdump is being run) to intelligently name the remote file, but of course, adapt this to your needs (maybe include a timestamp in the name, if that's useful).

Alternative example with UNIX timestamp remote file naming:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 port 8801 -w - | ssh ${remote_host} "cat > $(hostname)_$(date +%s).pcap"
```

Comment: I have tried the `$(hostname).pcap ` could not be opened by wireshark. tcpdump manual says the file format depends on the file suffix, maybe it does not understand the `cat >> $(hostname).pcap` well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the results you want with a separate `nc` process which listens on the server where `tcpdump` runs and duplicates it to the remote server.

You can make `nc` listen and forward with (as an example):

```
 nc -k -l localhost 9901 | nc 192.168.12.5 9901
```

then you can connect any `tcpdump` session you need with

```
 tcpdump -i eth0 port 8801 -w a.pcap | nc localhost 9901
```

The `-k` flags "*Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed.*"

Please keep in mind that if you're using a Debian based distro, there's a know bug:

> The `netcat-traditional` package on Debian/Ubuntu does not keep listening as > it should. In that case use the `netcat-openbsd` package instead.

Comment: nc listener only accepts one connection? I tried to run another tcpdump on a 2nd server, and it exits with `broken pipe`

Comment: @Tiina unfortunately I've missed that point. `nc` accepts only one connection at a time.